# How to conditional await to avoid duplicate code

Tags: javascript, async-await

Let's say I have an async function that does something asynchronously:

```
const async doSomething = (isAwaitResponse) => {
   // SOME LONG OPERATION THAT MIGHT TAKE SOME TIME.
   if (isAwaitResponse) - AWAIT TO RESOLVE THE PROMISE.
   if (!isAwaitResponse) - JUST RETURN "OK" or something. 
};
```

And from my REST API perspective I want to await this function or not determine on a parameter I pass to my route, for example:

```
app.post('/testing', async (req, res) => {
  const { isAwaitResponse } = req.body;
  let result = null;
  if (isAwaitResponse) {
    result = await doSomething(isAwaitResponse);
  } else {
    result = doSomething(isAwaitResponse);
  }
  return res.json(result);
});
```

My question is, is there any conditional await in Javascript? Something that I can just do, for example:

```
const result = isAwaitResponse ?? await : doSomething();
return res.json(result);
```

If this does not exist, are there any plans to do it?
I hate to write duplicate code, and sometimes I want to wait for a response and sometimes not.

Thanks.

Comment: In your example, you're jsonifying a Promise in the second case.

Comment: Yea this doesn't make a lot of sense. How does `doSomething()` know whether it should do something that requires awaiting a Promise?

Comment: Let's say this function do some long async operation on the server and sometimes I want to wait for the result and sometimes not.

Comment: That still makes `res.json(result)` useless (in case you don't await). What is your intention there?

Comment: My intention is that sometimes I do want to await the result (Online debug or something) and sometimes not.

Comment: And if you don't await it, you are not interested in the response?

Comment: @trincot Yes, exactly.

Comment: Why would u want to do that? The return type of this functions always gonna be a promise. In that case it might be better to just do a separete function which doesnt await the result

Comment: Simply `let p = doSomething(foo); if (foo) p = await p;`…!? Even if that makes little sense…

Comment: @deceze You got a point there. Thanks :)

Comment: In general sense if you need to decide to go async or not just use a proper synchronus function and depending on the case either return a promise or a value. It's that simple. Do not waste your time with silly abstractions like `async` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to avoid giving a promise object as argument to `res.json`, as that will just serialize to an empty object.

As in either case you need to execute `doSomething`, start with that, and then use a conditional operator to determine the argument to pass to `res.json`:

```
const promise = doSomething();
res.json(isAwaitResponse ? await promise : "OK");
```

As an alternative you could also consider using `await` in both cases, but differentiate in the expression that is awaited (a thenable or not):

```
const result = await ["OK", doSomething()][+isWaitResponse];
res.json(result);
```

This will also evaluate `doSomething()` in both cases, but after its execution `isWaitResponse` will determine whether that promise or just the constant "OK" will be awaited. In the latter case this still makes the call to `res.json(result)` to execute asynchronously, but it will be done in the same "task".

NB: in all this it is of course assumed that `doSomething` returns a promise immediately and has its main (longrunnning) logic implemented asynchronously.